# Problems with fread and fwrite

Tags: c, stream, fwrite, fread

I'm having some problems with a program that uses `fwrite` and `fread -> fread (void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*);`, when a set second `size_t` as any number different than zero it doesn't works.
Here is the code; it doesn't works this way, if anyone could help I would appreciate.

P.S.: if I substitute that sc's on the `read` and `write` function it works, but not as expected.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define TAM 10
#define sc 5

typedef struct str_score{
    float scr;
    char nome[TAM];
}score;

int main(){

    FILE *arq;
    int x;
    score a[sc], i={0.00,"-empty-"};

    if ((fopen("highscore.bin", "wb+"))==NULL){
        perror("Erro na abertura do arquivo\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fwrite(&i,sizeof(score), sc, arq);

    fread(a ,sizeof(score), sc, arq);

    for (x=0;x<sc;x++){
        printf("%s %.2f", a[x].nome,a[x].scr);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It's just that your compiler punishes you for the formatting of your code by emitting buggy machine code.

Comment: (Seriously, format/indent your code and check the return value of `fread()` and `fwrite()`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since `i` is not an array, the following line is not correct

   ```
   fwrite(&i,sizeof(score), sc, arq);
   ```

   This should be

   ```
   fwrite(&i,sizeof(score), 1, arq);
   ```

   You can write `sc` number of elements, only when you have an initialized array of size `sc` or more.
2. You are not accepting the return value of `fopen`. Change your `fopen` line to

   ```
   if ((arq = fopen("highscore.bin", "wb+"))==NULL){
   ```
3. Between the `fwrite` and `fread`, put a

   ```
   fseek(arq, 0, SEEK_SET);
   ```

This resets the file pointer to beginning of the file where you started writing.

Comment: Thank's for the comment, it works now. About the "fwrite(&i,sizeof(score), sc, arq);", I tought that would write i for sc times. I substituted that for this -

for(x=0;x<sc;x++)
fwrite(&i,sizeof(score), 1, arq);
Thank you again

Comment: `I tought that would write i for sc times.` - it actually reads starting from `&i` for `sc * sizeof(i)` bytes - which is why your `fread` which does a similar thing works fine.